# Tools for testing API

Tags: php, api, http, testing

I am developing a PHP web application on my desktop and currently working on its API. Its really hard and time consuming to test API functionality through browser or cURL. Is there any tool for Windows (7) that can help in sending POST/GET requests to a given URL and shows response?

May be a firefox plugin can work too if it allows to send custom post/get parameters (including multipart).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of programs or tools is not what stackoverflow is about... But you might want to search google with the phrase 'rest client for firefox' or similar. Personally I prefer a chrome plugin called `Postman`, and it might exist for firefox too. Good luck.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/restclient/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP Unit testing you could check out the [PHPUnit tutorial on the Pear site](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpunit.intro.php) or [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/).

I have found this link for you to test PHP Web Application Using [Flash Builder](http://files.zend.com/help/Flash-Builder-for-PHP/Help/build_a_web_(php)_application.htm).

In Specific to Sending POST/GET Request, [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) Would work great on Chrome Browser Or You can go for IDE [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

I am adding few more for **GET/POST** Clients for different browsers:

**Google Chrome**

[HTTP/REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)

**Mozilla Firefox**

[REST Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)

**Apple Safari**

[Cocoa REST Client](http://mmattozzi.github.io/cocoa-rest-client/)

**Opera**

[Simple REST Client](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/simple-rest-client/)

The [Apigee Console](https://apigee.com/console/others) supports a number of predefined APIs and a generic mode for any API. It has a nice snapshot feature where you can make a request and then send a link to anyone and they can view the request/response you made.

We do have [Hurl](https://www.hurl.it/) but I haven't tested it working.

You can give anyone of them a try as per your need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) in chrome or [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/restclient/) in Firefox

Also a better approach is to use an automation testing tool like [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) or a tool like [behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/) which has features like API Testing, Monitoring, Traffic monitoring. There is another tool like [Requestbin](http://requestb.in/) that sees what your HTTP client is sending or to inspect and debug webhook requests.